# a debug Error for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting an error while running a application. my servlet takes a request and tries to process it, I have the following code:

```
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    try {
        if (excludedPatterns != null && prepare.isUrlExcluded(request, excludedPatterns)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            prepare.setEncodingAndLocale(request, response);
            prepare.createActionContext(request, response);
            prepare.assignDispatcherToThread();
            request = prepare.wrapRequest(request);
            ActionMapping mapping = prepare.findActionMapping(request, response, true);
            if (mapping == null) {
                boolean handled = execute.executeStaticResourceRequest(request, response);
                if (!handled) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                execute.executeAction(request, response, mapping);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        prepare.cleanupRequest(request);
    }
}

public void destroy() {
    prepare.cleanupDispatcher();
}
```

but it reported an error

```
Source not found for ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 269
```

thanks.

Comment: That's not a real error message, is it? Please post the full stack trace.